# Where are linux packages hosted? (Debian in particular)

Tags: linux, debian, package-management

I'm trying to understand some things about package managers

Debian wheezy packages, like when you do `apt-get install example` and suppose you never added sources.

Where does `apt` look for the package

On launchpad and debian site only? if so, where exactly on launchpad, i tried to find my way but i was lost, this site is huge, does aptitude search the same host? suppose there's no `apt` and you have to go download it, you go to launchpad? supposing that the developer didn't have a site.

Does yum and pacman also search launchpad? What else?

And last question, about pip, does it only search PYPI.python.org?

Comment: launchpad is Ubuntu's repo, Fedora, CentOS and ArchLinux all have their own repos. There may be common servers/networks between the last three but not by design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian packages are hosted on the Debian servers and its mirrors. Launchpad is not a typical place for Debian packages. It's popular for Ubuntu repositories, though.

Where precisely `apt` downloads the packages you can find out by having a look at

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Here an example:

```
deb http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

The packages can then be found e.g. under `http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/debian/pool/main/…`

Aptitude uses the same `sources.list` file as `apt-get`. If no repositories were added, then `apt-get` cannot install software. You can add any sort of repository, neither affiliated with Debian, Launchpad or another site. Everybody can set up a repository. But be careful with adding a whole lot of random repositories, they might contain malware and it's rarely necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Really what a package manager really is a download manager it will essentially wget a file from a server e.g htt://www.example.com/package.tar.gz and then it would be  installed depending on the the developers instructions to /usr/bin/ in reference to where did it come from then it would come from a webserver which are all over the world even you could set up one with the same packages.

Comment: This is oversimplified to point of being wrong.